# Turn off color in bash for logs

Tags: bash, colors, sendmail, ansible

I am running Ansible on multiple machines and redirecting the output
to a file, say `log-$(date)`, which is mailed to me every day. The
output file has multiple text colors, how to turn them off? Sendmail
sends output which contains `[0;32m`, `[0;33m`, `[0;36m`, etc.

Is there an option in sendmail? Or in Ansible settings? (I don't want
to turn it off in Ansible.)

Comment: I am using ansible. Tail the log and use sendmail to send it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask the program that produces those colors to stop, or remove those colors yourself:

```
sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"
```

^I have this in an executable named `uncolor` so that I can do:

```
aProgramThatWontStopColoring | uncolor
```

Comment: It worked. Great.
`tail -32 log-2015-12-16_22-53 | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | sendmail "san1512@mailtest.com"`